# Texshade on Overleaf won't select amino acids by sequence

Tags: bugs, protein

I would like to highlight certain short sequences of amino acids in a protein sequence. Choosing them by specifying their numbers works, but since some of them occur several times I would prefer to select by sequence. Although I'm doing exactly as described in the user manual, it just ignores my `\shaderegion` command (it should choose the four first residues in the depicted stretch).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{texshade} 

\begin{document}

\begin{filecontents*}{protein.fasta}
>sp|P42566|EPS15_HUMAN Epidermal growth factor receptor substrate 15 OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=EPS15 PE=1 SV=2
MAAAAQLSLTQLSSGNPVYEKYYRQVDTGNTGRVLASDAAAFLKKSGLPDLILGKIWDLA
DTDGKGILNKQEFFVALRLVACAQNGLEVSLSSLNLAVPPPRFHDTSSPLLISGTSAAEL
PWAVKPEDKAKYDAIFDSLSPVNGFLSGDKVKPVLLNSKLPVDILGRVWELSDIDHDGML
DRDEFAVAMFLVYCALEKEPVPMSLPPALVPPSKRKTWVVSPAEKAKYDEIFLKTDKDMD
GFVSGLEVREIFLKTGLPSTLLAHIWSLCDTKDCGKLSKDQFALAFHLISQKLIKGIDPP
HVLTPEMIPPSDRASLQKNIIGSSPVADFSAIKELDTLNNEIVDLQREKNNVEQDLKEKE
DTIKQRTSEVQDLQDEVQRENTNLQKLQAQKQQVQELLDELDEQKAQLEEQLKEVRKKCA
EEAQLISSLKAELTSQESQISTYEEELAKAREELSRLQQETAELEESVESGKAQLEPLQQ
HLQDSQQEISSMQMKLMEMKDLENHNSQLNWCSSPHSILVNGATDYCSLSTSSSETANLN
EHVEGQSNLESEPIHQESPARSSPELLPSGVTDENEVTTAVTEKVCSELDNNRHSKEEDP
FNVDSSSLTGPVADTNLDFFQSDPFVGSDPFKDDPFGKIDPFGGDPFKGSDPFASDCFFR
QSTDPFATSSTDPFSAANNSSITSVETLKHNDPFAPGGTVVAASDSATDPFASVFGNESF
GGGFADFSTLSKVNNEDPFRSATSSSVSNVVITKNVFEETSVKSEDEPPALPPKIGTPTR
PCPLPPGKRSINKLDSPDPFKLNDPFQPFPGNDSPKEKDPEIFCDPFTSATTTTNKEADP
SNFANFSAYPSEEDMIEWAKRESEREEEQRLARLNQQEQEDLELAIALSKSEISEA
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{texshade}{protein.fasta}
\shadingmode{diverse}
\residuesperline{50}
\setdomain{1}{400..600}
\hideconsensus

\shaderegion{1}{ELDE}{Red}{Green}

\hidenames
\showruler{1}{top}
\end{texshade}

\end{document}
```

[This version on overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/read/vsssgsjjdrfs) includes the current texshade.sty file, their default one has known problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The author has now added this function for \shaderegion in the current version 1.26b on the texshade ctan.org page!